# Mounting samba share on ubuntu 14.04.5 desktop files are in readonly mode?

Tags: samba

I've mounted the sambashare on ubuntu using the following command

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.16/billing /home/user/Desktop/Billing -o username=username,password=password
```

The files are showing with a lock symbol on the mounted path ? im able to create new folder and files on the Billing folder but not able to edit any existing files on the share ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a permissions issue. Every new file/folder created on a share by the remote user, belongs to that user. That's why you have full access to the newly created stuff. The existing files though, belong to the local user who placed them there.

1. You can either change the ownership of the existing stuff so that they also belong the remote user: `sudo chown -R remoteUserName:remoteUserName shareName`
2. You can change the permissions of the existing files to allow **r/w** access by **others**: `sudo chmod -R o+rw shareName` which is a bit unsafe if your share is not protected by a password so that only verified users can access it.

Comment: i tried the first option sudo chown -R but says invalid user

Comment: Have you added the *remoteUserName* as a normal user on the host system?

Comment: I added it as sudo user